# how to cause man in the middle error on ssh login

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys

I want to cause this error message:

```
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@    WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!     @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
IT IS POSSIBLE THAT SOMEONE IS DOING SOMETHING NASTY!
Someone could be eavesdropping on you right now (man-in-the-middle attack)!
...
...
```

I know this has to do with the host key changing.  I want to trigger this error because I'm writing an ssh library and I need to test it against this, but I can't figure out what to do to cause it to appear.  I've altered the saved key in the local machine's `known_hosts`, I've altered the `id_rsa` on the remote machine.  Neither has worked.

How can I make this error appear when I try to login?

Comment: Change the key on the server or client but keep the other key the same.

Comment: I tried that, but it didn't work.  I just got the prompt to add the key again

Comment: Turns out I just didn't change it right (or something).  Not sure exactly what happened, but I replaced the key in `known_hosts` with the key for another server and it worked.  Add as an answer and I'll accept

Answer (score 2):

Lets assume you want to connect from you client to the `example.com` SSH server. It has some public key, which you already have in the `~/.ssh/known_hosts`.

The easiest way is to simulate that on your client:

- Generate a new key using `ssh-keygen`:

  ```
  ssh-keygen -t rsa -f rsa -P ""
  ```
- remove the old `known_hosts` and replace them with this key (prefix with the hostname):

  ```
  echo -n "example.com " > ~/.ssh/known_hosts
  cat rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
  ```

The error should appear, when you try to connect to `example.com`:

```
ssh exmaple.com
```

Comment: can you clarify on which machine I'm supposed to do what?

Comment: On the client. I will add it to the question